# Install ipdb to tox environment for development

Tags: python, tox, ipdb

I'm looking for a neat way to install `ipdb` in tox environments, when I'm using them for development. They're often recreated, so I need something other than single installation.

Any hints?

Comment: You can add `ipdb` to [tox requirements](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-requires).

Comment: @GrigoryFeldman That would apply to all environments, I'd like only to change the ones on my desktop.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ones on my desktop"? Do the change in your `tox.ini` file locally on your own computer but don't share this modification with other contributors, then. Are we missing some information here?

Comment: I don't quite want to change the `tox.ini` to prevent accidental commit.

Comment: @VlastimilZíma I understand. I don't know of any other easy solution. You could write your own plugin for _tox_ or _virtualenv_, but that would require a bit of work. On the other hand you probably could configure _git_ so that this one change is not accidentally committed locally or pushed to a remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have your own personal customization plugin for *tox* that would inject `ipdb` as dependency in the *tox* environments.

Such a plugin could look like this:

`tox_ipdb.py`

```
import tox

@tox.hookimpl
def tox_configure(config):
    for envconfig in config.envconfigs.values():
        envconfig.deps.append(tox.config.DepConfig('ipdb'))
```

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='tox-ipdb',
    version='0.0.0.dev0',
    py_modules=[
        'tox_ipdb',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'tox': 'ipdb = tox_ipdb',
    },
)
```

This would instruct *tox* to install *ipdb* in all the environments it creates. As long as it is installed only in your local environment alongside your `tox` installation, it will have no influence on others.

Comment: Great idea, I've published it https://pypi.org/project/tox-ipdb-plugin/

Comment: @VlastimilZíma Glad it could help.